# Is there a reversed function for mysql_escape_string?

Tags: php

So that I can change string like `I\'ll go` back to `I'll go`

Answer (score 2):

```
stripslashes()
```

Un-quotes a quoted string.

ex.:

```
$string = "This isn't good";

$string = mysql_escape_string($string);

echo "$string";
```

produces: This isn\'t good

```
$string = stripslashes($string);

echo "$string";
```

produces : This isn't good

Comment: Just an FYI from the php manual: "If magic_quotes_sybase is on, no backslashes are stripped off but two apostrophes are replaced by one instead."
http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: Keep in mind that stripslashes() is not aware of the MySQL connection charset. see http://ilia.ws/archives/103-mysql_real_escape_string-versus-Prepared-Statements.html

Comment: Neither is `mysql_escape_string`, which is why `mysql_real_escape_string` should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

`stripslashes()`

Answer (score 0):

No.

It's not really required:

$b=mysql_escape_string($a);

$a still contains the unescaped string.

C.